# Proof for a modular arithmetic identity.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove the following? Or is there a reference to the proof for this?

$$d \mod abc = d \mod a + a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{d}{a}\right\rfloor \mod b\right)+ab\left(\left\lfloor\frac{d}{ab}\right\rfloor \mod c\right)$$

Comment: BTW using $a \mod b = c$ to mean that $c$ is the unique remainder $0\le c < b$ when $a$ is divided by $b$ is *not* conventional and makes my teeth hurt to see it.  $a \mod b$ usually refers to the *equivalence class* of all numbers that have the the same remainder, not merely the least positive one.  As such you can't really mix them this way.

Comment: @fleablood I agree. But in computation, more than often not, one uses it to mean the unique remainder. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: The equivalence class modular equations usually use the following format:
$$a \equiv b \pmod n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d = r + ka; 0\le r < a$.  Then $r =$ what you are referring to as $d\mod a$.  And $k = [\frac da]$.

Let $k = s + mb; 0 \le s < b$ so $s = [\frac da] \mod b$ and $m =[\frac d{ab}]$

Let $m = t + nc; 0 \le t< c$ so $t = [\frac d{ab}] \mod c$

$d = r + ka=$

$r + (s+mb)a = r+(s+(t+nc)b)a = r + sa + tba + n*abc$

And $r + sa + tba \le  (a-1) + (b-1)a+ (c-1)ba = a-1 + ab -a +abc - ba = abc - 1$.

So $r + sa + tba = d \mod abc$.

And $r + sa + tba = d\mod a + a([\frac da] \mod b) + ab([\frac d{ab}] \mod c)$.

====

We can try to do it more directly.  By division algorithm:

for and $n,q$ there are unique integers $d,r$ so that $n = dq + r$ were $0 \le r < q$.

It's simple to see that $dq \le n < dq + q$ so $d \le \frac nq < d+1$ so $d = [\frac nq]$.

And this exercise, although it makes my teeth hurt to see it, seems to be taking $n \mod q$ to be and operation that is defined to be equal to $r$ as a definition. (So be it, I'm tired of arguing).

So $n = (n\mod q) + q*[\frac nq]$ is an identity. Furthermore if $n = a + q*[\frac nq]$ it follows that $a = (n\mod q)$.

Hence  $d = (d \mod a) + a([\frac da])$

$= (d \mod a) + a([\frac da]\mod b + b([\frac {[\frac da]}b]))$

$=(d \mod a) + a([\frac da]\mod b + b([\frac {[\frac da]}b]\mod c + c([\frac{[\frac {[\frac da]}b]}c])))$

$= (d\mod a) + a([\frac da]\mod b) + ab([\frac {[\frac da]}b]\mod c) + abc*([\frac{[\frac {[\frac da]}b]}c])$.

So it only remains to show that $[\frac {[\frac da]}b] = [\frac a{ab}]$ and that $[\frac{[\frac {[\frac da]}b]}c] =[\frac a{abc}]$; something I glided over in my above proof.

Simple enough:

Lemma:  $[\frac {[\frac mn]}k] = [\frac m{nk}]$ (for positive integers).

Proof: $[\frac mn] \le \frac mn < [\frac mn]+1$

$\frac{[\frac mn]}k \le \frac m{nk} <  \frac{[\frac mn]}k + \frac 1k$

$[\frac{[\frac mn]}k] \le\frac{[\frac mn]}k \le \frac m{nk} <  \frac{[\frac mn]}k + \frac 1k$

Meanwhile $[\frac{[\frac mn]}k]+ 1= [\frac{[\frac mn]}k]+ \frac kk > \frac{[\frac mn]}k$.  And as $[\frac mn]$ is an integer.  $[\frac{[\frac mn]}k]+ \frac {k-1}k \ge \frac{[\frac mn]}k$.

So $[\frac{[\frac mn]}k]  \le \frac m{nk} <  \frac{[\frac mn]}k + \frac 1k\le [\frac{[\frac mn]}k]+ \frac {k-1}k +\frac 1k = [\frac{[\frac mn]}k]+1$

So $[\frac m{nk}]=[\frac{[\frac mn]}k]$

So

$d= (d\mod a) + a([\frac da]\mod b) + ab([\frac {[\frac da]}b]\mod c) + abc*([\frac{[\frac {[\frac da]}b]}c])$

$= (d \mod a) +a([\frac da]\mod b) + ab([\frac {d}{ab}]\mod c)+ abc([\frac {d}{abc}])$.

And $d = (d\mod abc) + abc([\frac {d}{abc}])$.

So $d\mod abc = (d \mod a) +a([\frac da]\mod b) + ab([\frac {d}{ab}]\mod c)$

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just have one doubt.
How do we know for sure that $k\leq b$ and $m\leq c$? Could add the proof for these (i.e., if there is a way to rigorously show that this is true) to your answer as well?

Comment: Why should $k \le b$ or $m \le c$?   There is no reason or need for those to be true.

Comment: $k = s + mb$ so if $m > 1$ then $k > b$.  That's not not the point because $k =[\frac da]$ and $s = [\frac da]\mod b$.  So $[\frac da]$ could and probably is bigger than $b$.  It's $s =  [\frac da]\mod b$ that is smaller.

Comment: Very sorry, I meant $k\geq b$ and $m\geq c$.

Comment: Again, why should $k \ge b$ or $m \ge c$?  If $k < b$ then $m = 0$. If $m < c$ then $n = 0$.  No biggee.  Example: $2 \mod 105 = 2 = 2 \mod 3 + 2(0 \mod 5) + 2*5(0 \mod 7)$.  Or $8 \mod 105 = 8 \mod 3 + 3([\frac {8}{3}]\mod 5) + 15([\frac{8}{15}\mod 7) = 2 + 3*2 + 15*0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

Numerical example:
$$\begin{align}95 \mod \color{red}2\cdot \color{green}3\cdot \color{blue}7 = \color{purple}{\mathbf{11}} \Rightarrow \frac{95}{\color{red}2\cdot \color{green}3\cdot \color{blue}7}&=\frac{(1+94)}{\color{red}2\cdot 3\cdot 7}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot 47}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot (2+45)}{2\cdot \color{green}3\cdot 7}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot 2}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 15}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot 2}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot (1+14)}{2\cdot 3\cdot \color{blue}7}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{\color{red}2\cdot 2}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\frac{\color{red}2\cdot \color{green}3\cdot 1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 7}+2=\\
&=\frac{\color{purple}{\mathbf{11}}}{\color{red}2\cdot \color{green}3\cdot \color{blue}7}+2.\end{align}$$